# Error "error de compilación no se encontró el argumento con nombre"

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-office

Excel(VBA) me deja el siguiente mensaje:

> "error de compilación no se encontró el argumento con nombre"

Esto al momento de escribir dentro del textbox llamado : "txtBuscar"
siendo el código que ingrese el siguiente:

```
`Private Sub txtBuscar_Change()
filtro = "*" & Sheets("RESUMEN").txtBuscar.Text & "*"
Range("C5").AutoFilter field:=9, Criterial:=filtro
End Sub`
```

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola. Explica qué quieres conseguir. Porque, según parece por el código, quieres buscar el valor contenido en txtbuscar en la columna. Si es así, no puedes usar el Autofiltro, más que nada porque el autofiltro resume los valores de la columna que están en la columna "C" e igual lo que buscas no está en la columna.

Comment: Estás seleccionando solamente la celda C5 para filtrar y luego dices que vas a filtrar por la columna novena, pero has seleccionado solo la celda. Asegúrate de usar todo el rango que quieres filtrar.

Comment: @pcandido Quiero resolver la búsqueda por aquel textbox con autocompletado, para que buscar los datos correspondientes a esa fila, filtrando por los datos de la columna "C"